# What is the best solution to build a vue3 + ts + vite project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vite

I am new to vue amd feel confused how to combine vite,ts and vue3 together correctly.I want to know what is the best solution for this in vue, I will add vue route ,vuex later.

I have found two ways to create above project:

1. `npm init vite` (then I choose vue-ts)
2. `npm init vite-app <project-name>`(then I add typescript manually using npm)

My question is that:

1. The first way generates a `vite.config.ts` while the second way does not have one,why,and what is the best solution?
2. For `ts` code style in vue, what is the better style to write.I have seen many kinds of code to write a component in vue3
   with typescript,for example:

(1)

```
<script>
  import { defineComponent, computed } from 'vue'
  import { useStore } from 'vuex'
  import { key } from '../store'

  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    props: {
      msg: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      }
    },
    setup() {
      const store = useStore(key)
      const count = computed(() => store.state.count)

      return {
        count,
        inCrement: () => store.commit('increment')
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

(2)

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { isExternal } from '@/utils/validate'

@Component({
  name: 'SidebarItemLink'
})
export default class extends Vue {
  @Prop({ required: true }) private to!: string

  private isExternal = isExternal
}
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe not relevant, but NuxtJS is a framework build on top of Vue. It has build-in support for Typescript and also Vite. Check it out yourself and maybe you can get some good inspiration from it; https://nuxtjs.org/

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at this doc.

Answer (score 0):

For component code style, vue 3 recommend to use `defineComponent` + `composition api` + `template(or tsx)`

```
<template>
  <p class="msg">{{ msg }}</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    const msg = 'Hello World!';

    return {
      msg
    }
  }
})
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss" >

</style>
```